# SQL Query for a specific Result Set

Tags: sql

[image]

I could not format the text for better readibility. Hence, putting it up as an image.
Please suggest a way to devise a query.
Thanks

Comment: Every time you're posting sql row set as a picture, a little kitten dies

Comment: You apparently had all that information as text in an editor. Why on earth would you post plain text as an image?

Comment: Because I wasn't able to format it right. And I guess the main purpose was to put the question across in whatever way I could. Thanks for the suggestion though. I will try harder next time. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
SUM(CASE WHEN EMP.EMPNO <> EMP_ERROR.EMPNO THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DIFF_EMPNO,
SUM(CASE WHEN EMP.AGE <> EMP_ERROR.AGE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DIFF_AGE
FROM EMP
JOIN EMP_ERROR ON EMP.ID = EMP_ERROR.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
COUNT(SELECT * FROM EMP WHERE EMP.EMPNO != EMP_MIRROR.EMPNO) as DIFF_EMPNO,
COUNT(SELECT * FROM EMP WHERE EMP.AGE != EMP_MIRROR.AGE) as DIFF_AGE

FROM EMP
JOIN EMP_ERROR
```

Try that